# How to retrieve Django list as array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm sending django list from view.py to my javascript. But when I receive the list in javscript, it only return me as string. I tried to print the type of the variable but it show me false which mean its not array list. So how can I retrieve the list as array in Javascript?

View.py

```
    mergedCompare = [item_listAssigned[f'subject{i}'] + ': ' + item_listAssigned[f'serial{i}'] for i in range(1, len(item_listAssigned) // 2 + 1)]
            global context
            context = {
                'mergedCompare': mergedCompare
            }
```

`mergedCompare = ['EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR']`

JavaScript:

```
        var assignedDevices = "{{mergedCompare|safe}}"
        const list = assignedDevices;
        console.log(Array.isArray(list)) //false , not array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the JSON content as a JavaScript script with the [**`|json_script`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script). Then you can load the JSON blobk with `JSON.parse(…)`:

```
{{ mergedCompare|json_script:"mergedCompare" }}

<script>
var assignedDevices = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mergedCompare').textContent);
const list = assignedDevices;
console.log(Array.isArray(list))
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another few approaches in addition to previous answer:

- using [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter

```py
# your view code
...
return render(request, 'some.html', context = {"my_list": ["item1", "item2"]})

# your template code
{{ my_list|safe }}.forEach  // array
```

- dump to/from JSON

```py
import json

# your view code
...
mylist = json.dumps(mylistraw)
return render(request, 'some.html', context = {"my_list": mylist})

# your template code
var mylist = JSON.parse("{{mylist}}")
```